# How to fix 'ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysql'' error in Python file when debugging?

Tags: python-3.x, mysql-python

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysql' when debug Python file
I've run in "Run Code" mode in VS Code and it work properly. But any time I switch to "Run Python file" or "Debug Python file", it always appear and stop in import row

```
import mysql.connector
```

Have install mysql-connector and run code properly